# How to make whole screen scrollable rather than just the recyclerview inside it?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uybd7.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0geOs.jpg)

look at the two images above. It is a fragment in which there is textviews, searchviews, and recyclerviews. The problem is all views except recyclerview is fixed and is not scrollable. How can i make the whole screen scollable?

This is xml code below, here, just recyclerview seems to be scrolling while all the other views are fixed to there places. I want to make it so that when i scroll, all the elements should move.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDrops"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:shadowColor="#40000000"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="5"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:text="Drops"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/svHomeSearch"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/svHomeSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Search"
    android:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_icon"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvCategories"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvDrops" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvCategories"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/svHomeSearch"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvExplore"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="qwertyuioasdfghjklzxcvbnmqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbn" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvExplore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:shadowColor="#40000000"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="5"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:text="Explore"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rvWallpaperView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cvCategories" />


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvWallpaperView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="56dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvExplore"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_blueprint" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CoordinatorLayout & AppBarLayout, try below

```
<CoordinatorLayout  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
  <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
  </AppBarLayout>
  
   << rest of the UI of yours >> 

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Heshan Sandeepa appreciate your fast response. I have edited the question and added my code, Could you show me what you mean ? because when i changed to cordinator layout, i was not able to put everything to its places.

Comment: Replace ' << rest of the UI of yours >> ' with your whole code. Also, remove the Toolbar tag since you don't have a tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

> Use `Nested Scrollview`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```